# Ehcache Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/pool/sizeof/JvmInformation

Tags: weblogic, ehcache, terracotta

My organization is working on a POC for implementing ehcache using terracotta server version 4.0.5. Everything worked fine while testing using my local machine.

When we deployed our code to our web application it's able to connect to the TSA just fine but I'm receiving the below exception while attempting to create an instance of the CacheManager.

I've verified all the required jars are in the classpath.

ehcache-ee-2.7.5.jar
 
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
 
slf4j-jdk14-1.6.6.jar
 
terracotta-toolkit-runtime-ee-4.0.5.jar

They are in the WEB-INF/lib folder of my web application WAR. We're running on weblogic 10.3.2 with a JRE of jrmc-3.1.2-1.6.0.

Does anyone have any ideas on what would cause such an error? Any help is appreciated.

```
: org.terracotta.toolkit.nonstop.NonStopToolkitInstantiationException: org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitRuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/pool/sizeof/JvmInformation 
at com.terracotta.toolkit.AsyncToolkitInitializer.getToolkit(AsyncToolkitInitializer.java:46) 
at com.terracotta.toolkit.AsyncToolkitInitializer.getToolkit(AsyncToolkitInitializer.java:31) 
at com.terracotta.toolkit.NonStopToolkitImpl.getInitializedToolkit(NonStopToolkitImpl.java:88) 
at com.terracotta.toolkit.NonStopToolkitImpl.shutdown(NonStopToolkitImpl.java:277) 
at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.ToolkitInstanceFactoryImpl.shutdown(ToolkitInstanceFactoryImpl.java:265) 
at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.shutdown(TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:142) 
at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.ClusteredInstanceFactoryWrapper.shutdown(ClusteredInstanceFactoryWrapper.java:121) 
at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient.shutdownClusteredInstanceFactoryWrapper(TerracottaClient.java:159) 
at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient.shutdown(TerracottaClient.java:153) 
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395) 
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:265) 
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1123) 
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1099) 
at com.hmsy.cts.cache.HMSCacheManager.getCacheInstance(HMSCacheManager.java:22) 
at com.hmsy.cts.cache.CacheSearchAgent.executeSearch(CacheSearchAgent.java:41) 
at com.hmsy.cts.delegate.SearchRecipient.work(SearchRecipient.java:68) 
at com.hmsy.shr.event.ECEventWorkerThreadSafe.doWork(ECEventWorkerThreadSafe.java:39) 
at com.hmsy.cts.web.CTServiceListener.actionPerformed(CTServiceListener.java:65) 
at com.hmsy.shr.event.ECEventService.fireEvent(ECEventService.java:118) 
at com.hmsy.cts.web.CTSearchServlet.processRequest(CTSearchServlet.java:126) 
at com.hmsy.cts.web.CTSearchServlet.doPost(CTSearchServlet.java:73) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:499) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:248) 
at com.hmsy.shr.web.ControllerServlet.processRequest(ControllerServlet.java:292) 
at com.hmsy.shr.web.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:316) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56) 
at com.hmsy.shr.web.filter.BroadcastMessageFilter.doFilter(BroadcastMessageFilter.java:62) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3592) 
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) 
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2202) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1432) 
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201) 
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error because Ehcache gets NullPointerException when trying to find JRockit JVM parameters. Try using regular JVM, not JRockit. It should fix the problem.